# PC Mass Effect 3: Local Profile transferred to Online Profile

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Can you transfer your saved game/achievements from your Local Profile to an Online Profile so I can play multiplayer?

Comment: Have you tried playing multiplayer?  Everything should just work.

Answer (score 1):

Your achievements are linked to your account, which you already have since you're playing the game. You shouldn't have to do anything to play the multiplayer outside of clicking on the actual Multiplayer button.

(Which is to say, your Origin/console account has your achievements already saved to it, and since your progress through the single-player campaign has no bearing at all on the multiplayer you wouldn't need to enable cloud saving either.)